# Remove columns from a CSV using CMD/Batch

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I currently have a CSV I download from a vendor which has data in it I do not require before importing it into our system.

I need to removed some columns from the CSV using a batch file as we are on citrix we have not got powershell as an option.

There are no column headers and below is what the CSV looks like:

```
"9826XXXXXXXXXX217","60007834        ","    10.00","D","22/11/2018"
"9826XXXXXXXXXX324","60008504        ","    12.00","D","22/11/2018"
"9826XXXXXXXXXX414","60010605        ","    12.00","D","22/11/2018"
"9826XXXXXXXXXX013","60011385        ","    12.00","D","22/11/2018"
```

I need the output to be 2nd, 3rd, 5th column.

```
"60007834        ","    10.00","22/11/2018"
"60008504        ","    12.00","22/11/2018"
"60010605        ","    12.00","22/11/2018"
"60011385        ","    12.00","22/11/2018"
```

Comment: for more complex csv manipulation with batch files you can take a look at [this](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?style=29&f=3&t=6184&sid=a114b9bd1d6848d8f1964dba3faba85f)

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share your efforts!

Comment: @Echo off
For %%F in (*.txt) do ( 
    (for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%F) do Call :Split %%A
    ) > "C:\Run Folder\%%~nF_New.txt"
)
goto :Eof
:Split
if "%~2"=="" goto :eof
Echo(%2,%3,%5
move "*.txt" "C:\Archive" >nul



The above is what I ended with which takes columns 2,3,5  and pushes it to an 
output file which mirrors the old file name with "_New" and it removes the blank line at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there are possibly commas inside the fields,
use a call to a sub passing the quoted arguments:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\23\SO_53444017.cmd
@Echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%A in (test.csv) do Call :Split %%A
) > test_New.csv
goto :Eof
:Split
Echo(%2,%3,%5
```

---

```
> type test_New.csv
"60007834        ","    10.00","22/11/2018"
"60008504        ","    12.00","22/11/2018"
"60010605        ","    12.00","22/11/2018"
"60011385        ","    12.00","22/11/2018"
```

**Edit: Variant processing all *.csv files (appending `_New` to the name)**

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\23\SO_53444017.cmd
@Echo off
For %%F in (*.csv) do ( 
    (for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%F) do Call :Split %%A
    ) > "X:\Path\%%~nF_New.csv"
)
goto :Eof
:Split
Echo(%2,%3,%5
```

Comment: Thanks, this works a treat, anyway I could have the file name as a wild character like: (*.csv), when I try do that it returns a blank file

Comment: You'll need an outer for loop to enumerate the files. See edit to the answer.

Comment: I have been playing with the bat file recently and I have a couple more questions if you dont mind. Sorry that I was slow to reply to your alterations the last time.

The Last row of data is showing as ", , ," basically blank data because it was a footer total.

How could I add that to the batch file to delete that row if it is blank?

Also id like the new old file to be moved after to an archive location?

Comment: just following the label `:split` insert an `if "%~2"=="" goto :eof` or a similar check on other columns

Comment: is there a way to move the original file to an archived location?

Comment: There is only one redirection to change to directly save in the folder you'd like so `) > "%~dpnF_New.csv"`  --> `) > "X:\Your\path\%~nF_New.csv"` But this should be a new question and my answer here deserves an upvote ;-)

Comment: Im sorry just need to try get this all done :P 
I get this error when I add this to my batch file:
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~nF_New.csv"

Comment: Sorry missed one % sign, see changed answer. How to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: You have been amazing thanks so much for your help buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Not too difficult really.

from batch file, assuming file name is `test.csv`

```
(for /f "tokens=2,3,5 delims=," %%i in (test.csv) do echo %%i,%%j,%%k) > newcsv.csv
```

This will simply write values 2,3,5 to the new csv file..

To run it from cmdline instead, simply remove one of each `%`

```
(for /f "tokens=2,3,5 delims=," %i in (test.csv) do echo %i,%j,%k) > newcsv.csv
```

Please note, this assumes the data within your values do not contain `,` if they do, we need to make some changes.