# Remove Fields and Records of .CSV using .BAT file

Tags: csv, batch-file

First, I've came across a few different post related to this type of question but none of those solutions really solves my issue.

I am unable to change how my system exports the required .CSV file.

If possible I would like to run a .bat file that corrects each .csv file in a specific directory and saves a new file with existingname_new.csv

1)Each record of the .CSV has the first 9 fields blank. "A to I" (would like these to be removed.)
Data in our file starts in "J", we need this to be "A"

**Sample Records**:  (data has been changed for confidentiality)

```
,,,,,,,,,"0000012345",1/1/2021,"000023456","Metal Machine Vendor A",,"1,000.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,"JKL",1/1/2021,"000023457","Metal Machine Vendor B",,"1,000.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,"INTR",1/1/2021,"000023458","Metal Machine Vendor C",,"1,000.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

2)Delete any record that contains "JKL" or "INTR"
in the sample record above, column "J" either contains a number "0000012345", "JKL" or "INTR"

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444017/remove-columns-from-a-csv-using-cmd-batch)
The solution above copies specific field to a new file but when trying to use double digits like %10,%11,%12
it doens't recconize double digit numbers a "%10" it sees "%1" and adds O to the data.

This solution also wouldn't remove the JKL or INTR rows as needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
,,,,,,,,,12364,1/1/2023,30288,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,12365,1/1/2023,30308,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,12366,1/1/2023,30441,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,12367,1/1/2023,30472,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,12368,1/1/2023,30490,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,12369,1/1/2023,31021,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,ACH,1/1/2023,30070,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,ACH,1/1/2023,30602,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,ACH,1/1/2023,30092,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,ACH,1/1/2023,31010,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,WIRE,1/1/2023,30498,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,WIRE,1/1/2023,31043,account name,,"1,000.00"
,,,,,,,,,WIRE,1/1/2023,30954,account name,,"1,000.00"
```

This code is what im currently using. It runs through each file in "E:\batch csv test" directory, creating a new file with "existingname_New.csv)

```
For %%F in (*.csv) do ( 
    (for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ('findstr /rv ""ACH" "WIRE"" %%F') do @echo %%a)>"E:\batch csv test\%%~nF_New.csv"
)
```

Comment: unclear: remove lines with `"INT` or remove lines with `"INTR"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` treats consecutive delimiters as one, so it's easy to remove the leading empty rows. I wouldn't put the burden of removing lines to the `for` loop when it's easy to filter the lines beforehand:

```
(for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ('findstr /rv "\"JKL\" \"INT.*\"" existingname.csv') do @echo %%a)>existingname_new.csv
```

Output with your sample data:

```
"0000012345",1/1/2021,"000023456","Metal Machine Vendor A",,"1,000.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

It's not clear whether you want to remove "any line that contains `INT`" or "any line that contains `INTR`. If it's the second, replace `\"INT.*\"` with `\"INTR\"`  (`\"` is an escaped quote to tell `findstr` to search for a literal quote)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did test this using the sample data in the post and it did work. When i moved this over to my real file data and actually replaced "JLK" & "INTR" with the real abbreviations in my data it doesn't remove those rows..... Second - how can i loop this file so it just creates new files for every file in the directory vs defining a specific file name? Again thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know how your real data looks like - You may have to adapt `findstr`'s searchpattern. To loop over several files, use another `for` loop: `for %%b in (existing*.csv) do ...

Comment: I have successfully modified the code and it now works. Code added to bottom of original post.